# Why does this classList like shows the error

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="todos.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul>
        <li><span>X</span> Do Programming</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Do More Programming</li>
        <li><span>X</span> Do more and more Programming</li>
    </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="todos.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

css

```
.toggleli {
text-decoration: line-through;
color: grey;
```

}

Javascript

```
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
li[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
    li[i].classList.toggle("toggleli");
});
}
```

This is the error

```
todos.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
    at HTMLLIElement.<anonymous>
```

But when i change the 
`li[i].classList.toggle("toggleli");` 
to 
`this.classList.toggle("toggleli");` 
the error goes away. Whats the problem with 
`li[i].classList and li.classList` 
inside the for loop because outside that for loop it doesn't show the error but i have to toggle all the li's so i have to put it inside the loop

Comment: Because all of your `li` elements are getting an event handler that each rely on the `i` variable from your loop, each event handler shares the same, one varaible `i` and, by the time you click on any of them, the loop has terminated with a final value for `i` that is one higher than the highest index in your collection returned by `.querySelectorAll()`. You have a "closure" around the `i` variable. If you can avoid the shared `i` variable, the issue won't happen. That can be done in a variety of ways, but the simplest is to just write `this.classList...`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: all things are correct wrap your function within 
 window.onload=function(){var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for(i=0; i < li.length; i++) {
li[i].addEventListener("click", function() { 
    li[i].classList.toggle("toggleli");
});
}  }

Comment: this error will comoe usually when your script is executed first instead of DOM . to make sure DOM is loading please use windo.onload. or document.readyfunction of jquery

Answer (score 0):

Use `this` instead of `li[i]` in click event

```js
var li = document.querySelectorAll("li");

for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
  li[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("toggleli");
  });
}
```

```css
.toggleli {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>X</span> Do Programming</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Do More Programming</li>
  <li><span>X</span> Do more and more Programming</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why does this.classList works but li[i].classList doesn't ?

Comment: @Jolten Read my comment to your original question for an explanation.

Comment: why downvote ??